# Free up memory after using scanner on large text file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, java.util.scanner

If I run the Scanner code below once, it runs flawlessly.
If I run it a second time, my app crashes and I get an "Out of memory" error in LogCat.
How do I go about freeing up the memory used by the initial run so that the app won't crash on the second run?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated

```
try
{
myString = new Scanner(new File(myFilePath)).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Additional misc. info:
The purpose of the code is to load the entire contents of a large (1.5MB) text file into a string.
The exact error message in LogCat is: *Out of memory on a 4194320-byte allocation*
The code is being run in an AsyncTask background thread.
The try/catch was added automatically by eclipse. I don't know if it's formatted properly or not.
I tried emptying *myString* to free memory before the second run but that didn't help.
I've tried using other methods to load the file into a string (including the often-recommended apache Utils methods) and settled on this method because it's incredibly fast compared to the other methods I've tried.

Comment: Dont use Scanner, use FileReader instead or an InputBufferedStream. err BufferedInputStream.

Comment: are you sure you don't have a memory leak somewhere? 1.5MB file doesn't look that big. anyway you can force garbage collector with `system.gc()`

Comment: @lelloman I'm now using Eclipse Memory Analyzer to determine what's going on. It shows that, once the 1.5 MB of text is sent to my TextView, the TextView then uses 7.1MB of memory, which doesn't leave enough free memory for the Scanner to run a second time. Now I need to find out if using 7.1MB of memory to display 1.5 MB of text is normal.

Comment: I don't know but it sounds a little weird, is the textview scrollable?

Comment: @lelloman Yeah, it's scrollable. I just removed all of the line breaks from the file and now the TextView only uses 3.2MB while displaying all of the text. Apparently line breaks make a big difference. The file is a collection of English words with one word per line, which means a lot of line breaks (about 45,000).

Comment: @Shark Might you happen to have usage examples for me? Every FileReader example I've tried thus far took longer than 15 minutes to read the file into a string and the only BufferedInputStream example that I found used the depreciated "readLine", and it caused the app to crash. Edit: I got the BufferedInputStream example to work but it too took longer than 15 minutes to read the file into a string.

Comment: Nah, after looking into it, I found out Scanner was much better than I thought, so it's a very viable solution. My bad. On the other hand, might I suggest trying something like this after using the string? `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) System.gc();` and see if it makes a difference.